# Composer install behind https proxy

Tags: https, proxy, composer-php

On a new Server in my network i try to setup a composer project and having trouble with my internal proxy. The proxy settings are set in /etc/environment for http and https (upper and lowercase). The output i'm getting is as follows:

```
$ composer.phar diag

Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking HTTP proxy: OK
Checking HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri: OK
Checking HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri: FAIL
Unable to assess the situation, maybe github is down (The "https://api.github.com/repos/Seldaek/jsonlint/zipball/1.0.0" file could not be downloaded: Peer certificate CN=`codeload.github.com' did not match expected CN=`api.github.com'
failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy)
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

The proxy CA certificate is properly installed and working on curl, wget and git. But it looks like composer has problems to evaluate the certificates against each other, because of my own CA. The https proxy is changing the certificates (like a man in the middle and i can't change the proxy [company security]) and this probably kills it.

Before you ask: i already tried setting the HTTP(S)_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI export value.

Does someone know this behavior and has a workaround?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sry, no, i had to do it without proxy.

Comment: Unfortunately me too.